# Why is height of a complete binary tree O(log n)?

Tags: algorithms

A complete binary tree has $n$ nodes. Then for height $h$, $n=2^h-1$. At every “layer” of height, the number of nodes gets doubled. So we have $1+2^{(2-1)}+2^{(3-1)}+...+2^{(h-1)}=2^h-1$ nodes, for height $h$.
Thus $h=log_2(n+1)$. I understand this.
But how does inserting a new element into this take time $O(log_2n)$ and not $O(log_2(n+1))$?

Comment: Who says it's not $O(\log_2(n+1))$?

Comment: To paraphrase my university’s slides: When I have $n$ nodes, number of levels is at most $log_2n + 1$, insert() takes time $O(log_2n)$. This is with reference to heaps.

Answer (score 2):

Just because they say it's $O(\log_2(n))$, that doesn't mean it can't also be $O(\log_2(n+1))$. In fact, we have
$$
O(\log_2(n)) = O(\log_2(n+1))
$$
and the two complexity categories are entirely equal. We see this because on one hand we have
$$
f(n)\in O(\log_2(n))\implies f(n)\leq c\cdot \log_2(n)\leq c\cdot\log_2(n+1)\\
\implies f(n)\in O(\log_2(n+1))
$$
(where $c$ is some constant), while on the other hand we have
$$
f(n)\in O(\log_2(n+1))\implies f(n)\leq d\cdot\log_2(n+1)\leq d\cdot 2\log_2(n)\\
\implies f(n)\in O(\log_2(n))
$$
(where $d$ is some constant). Since the two are equal, the simpler alternative is often preferred over the more transparent option.

Answer (score 1):

Because
$f(n)
\in O(\log_2(n))
\iff
f(n)
\in O(\log_2(n+1))
$,
and it is convenient
to use the simpler form.